# EM4095 Wiegand rfid arduino uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, rfid, wiegand

I have buy a rfid long distance Wiegand  EM4095,

I have found a code but I need to replace the id tag,

I need to find the way to put my cod cards or tags

this is the code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define ADD_TAG_CODE "000736087" //change this ID with your own card TAG
#define DEL_TAG_CODE "000555859" //change this ID with your own card 

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX
String msg;
String ID ; //string to store allowed cards

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Serial Ready");

mySerial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("RFID Ready");
}

char c;

void loop(){

while(mySerial.available()>0){
c=mySerial.read();
msg += c;
Serial.println(msg); //Uncomment to view your tag ID
Serial.println(msg.length());
}
msg=msg.substring(1,13);
if(msg.indexOf(ADD_TAG_CODE)>=0) add();
else if(msg.indexOf(DEL_TAG_CODE)>=0) del();
else if(msg.length()>10) verifica();
msg="";

}

void add(){
Serial.print("What TAG do you wanna grant access?: ");
msg="";
while(msg.length()<13){
while(mySerial.available()>0){
c=mySerial.read();
msg += c;
}
}
if(ID.indexOf(msg)>=0) {
Serial.println("\nAccess already granted for this card.");
msg="";
}
else{
Serial.print("Card: ");
Serial.println(msg);
ID += msg;
ID += ",";
//Serial.print("ID: ");
//Serial.println(ID);
msg="";
Serial.println("Access granted for this card.");
}

}

void del(){
msg="";
Serial.print("What TAG do you wanna deny access?: ");
while(msg.length()<13){
while(mySerial.available()>0){
c=mySerial.read();
msg += c;
}
}
msg=msg.substring(1,13);
if(ID.indexOf(msg)>=0){
Serial.println(msg);
Serial.println("TAG found. Access for this card denied.");
//ID.replace(card,"");
int pos=ID.indexOf(msg);
msg="";
msg += ID.substring(0,pos);
msg += ID.substring(pos+15,ID.length());
ID="";
ID += msg;
//Serial.print("ID: ");
//Serial.println(ID);
} else Serial.println("\nTAG not found or already denied");
msg="";
}

void verifica(){
msg=msg.substring(1,13);
if(ID.indexOf(msg)>=0) Serial.println("Access granted.");
else
Serial.println("Access denied.");
}
```

[Serial output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYJpk.png)

Somebody can help my to solve this or send me a link with project ?

How can modify manually stored cards?

Were are stored ID's in memory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```
 long keys[] = { 0002573238 };
```

0002573238 this your rfid tag code.
if you have any more problem visit here https://www.instructables.com/id/Reading-RFID-Tags-with-an-Arduino/

hope this will help you.

thanks!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but I have error
Serial.print(val, BYTE);
                   ^               
exit status 1
The keyword "BYTE" is no longer supported.